# 9V, 2A DC power supply

Tags: power-supply, dc

Please i Need a circuit diagram for a DC power supply that can give an output 9V, 2A. I designed one but it could not power the device for which i designed it because the current output is less than the rating of the device.

Comment: Use two LT3080 in parallel. They'll provide 2.2A.

Comment: What voltage are you running from?  You really want a switched mode power supply for that kind of current.

Comment: If you show us the circuit you designed, we might be able to help you understand why it is not working they way you wanted it to.

Comment: If this uses line power as input, then just buy one.

Comment: I am running from a 220V AC source. I want a Switched mode power supply

Comment: Then like I said, go buy one.

Comment: This question is overly broad and can not be answered in its current form.

Answer (score 3):

**(1) BUY ONE!**

**(2) DIY**

[Reference design library of AC-DC converters](http://designs.digikey.com/library/search/4294959904/4294959863#N=4294959863+4294959904)

[Narrowed down to around your spec = 3 designs](http://designs.digikey.com/library/search/4294959904/4294959863#N=8458+8463+9698+10295+10297+10298+4294959863+4294959904&page=1)

---

One example:

[From here](http://designs.digikey.com/library/4294959904/4294959863/408)

VIPER53 based.
24 Watts max.

[VIOER application note](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/APPLICATION_NOTE/CD00040933.pdf)

[VIPER IC datasheet](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00084589.pdf)

Typical use:

[image]

---

**TOPSWITCH**

[Related TOPSwitch reference design report](http://www.powerint.com/sites/default/files/PDFFiles/rdr242.pdf)

[TOPSWITCH family discussion](http://www.powerint.com/sites/default/files/product-docs/topjx_family_datasheet.pdf)

[Related application note](http://www.powerint.com/sites/default/files/product-docs/an47.pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very vague. Do you want a linear or switch-mode supply? What is the range of input voltages? How accurate must the 9V be, and what ripple is allowed? Do you need (over) current protection?

For a linear, an LM317 in TO3 can supply at least 1.5A. That might be enough. The LM317 datahseet shows a two-transistor linear 'booster' and also some switch mode (!) circuits up to 4A. You could even go retro and check a ua723 datasheet and use a 2N3055 pass transistor!

As always, a more to the point question will probably result in more approriate answers...

Comment: It is actually an AC to DC power supply. I will prefer Switched mode. Thank you

Comment: There are 'some' more questions to answer! And an obvious question is of course "have you considered an off-the-shelve solution"?